# While building Api, builder gives me error

Tags: exception, scope

I can't build `API.Builder` gives me this exception

I have seen many materials but nothing helps me actually. Can you please help me:

> ServiceType:
> Door.DataAccess.Contracts.Repositories.IUnitOfworkRepository Lifetime:
> Scoped ImplementationType:
> Door.DataAccess.Repositories.UnitOfWorkRepository

and same about all services and repositories, I have checked all these issues, have registered dbcontext as well?

second exception:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'WebAPI.Data.AppDbContext' while attempting to activate
> 'Door.DataAccess.Repositories.UnitOfWorkRepository